# preventDefault and oncontextmenu

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I need to avoid `$('.lorem').on('contextmenu', function...` - long story why.

Want the same using `oncontextmenu`.

Getting the error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined"

Any help?

```js
function fn(e){
e.preventDefault();
console.log('lorem');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='parent' oncontextmenu='fn()'>lorem</div>
```

Comment: I know you say it's a long story, but it may be worth explaining briefly why you can't listen for the event, just in case it makes possible answers invalid or anyone can suggest alternative solutions.

Comment: @DBS I need a list of all my functions inside Notepad++. Using `$('.lorem').on('click'...` - the function is not properly named in the functions list

Comment: You can keep the function exactly how it is and listen for the event with something like `$(".parent").on('contextmenu',fn)`, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @DBS, yes I can, but in that case name of the function is missing it the function list.

Comment: I'm not sure how my suggestion could have any effect on the functions listed in the editor. The function would be identical to what you're calling from `oncontextmenu='fn()'`, it would just be called from a different location. But if the editor doesn't like it I guess working around it is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me

```js
function fn(e) {e.preventDefault(); console.log('lorem');}

window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  document.querySelector(".parent").oncontextmenu=fn
});
```

```html
<div class='parent'>lorem</div>
```